# Publisher can not convert to String

Tags: c#

How can I convert String to Label.

```
string str = "Test String";
object objString = (object)str;

Label lbl = (Label)objString; //InvalidCastException was unhandled

lbl.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Weird question? Sounds like how do I make a cat from a dog...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` isn't `Label`.. (you can't convert `String` to `Label`)

try this:

```
string str = "Test String";

Label lbl = new Label() { Text = str }; 

lbl.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Label lbl = this.Controls["label" + i] as Label;
 lbl.BackColor = Color.Red;
 lbl.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
Thank you for your previous help.How do I write this code in vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can convert string to label, with few tricks

```
public class myLabel:Label
{
  public static explicit operator myLabel(string text)
   {
     myLabel lbl = new myLabel();
     lbl.Text = text;
     return lbl;
   }
}
```

and then in your presentation

```
    myLabel lbl = new myLabel();
    lbl = (myLabel)"abc1234";
    form1.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Comment: Based on the question posed, this answer could lead to even more confusion... , however nice it is :-)

Comment: Is obvious that sugar is sugar and sugarcube is sugarcube, convert does not mean EQUAL. its mean CONVERT